# How to get total value on dynamic value?

Tags: php, jquery, input

I have form like this :

```
<input type='hidden' name='seq' id='idseq' value='1' />
<div id='add_field' class='locbutton'><a href='#' title='Add'>Add</a></div>
<div id='remove_field' class='locbutton2'><a href='#' title='Delete'>Delete</a></div>
<div id="idcover">
1.<br />
<div class="group">
<div class="satu"><input type='text' name='score[1][]' id='score[1][]'></div>
<div class="dua"><input type='text' name='weight[1][]' id='weight[1][]'> %</div>
<div class="tiga"><input type='text' name='weightscore[1][]' id='weightscore[1][]' 
disabled></div>
</div>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div id='idtotalcover' class='totalcover'>
Total <div class='total'><input type='text' name='total' id='idtotal' disabled /></div>
</div>
```

This is the jquery script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
function ()
{
  $("input[id^=score],input[id^=weight]").bind("keyup", recalc);
  recalc();
var counter = $("#idseq").val();
$("#add_field").click(function () 
{
  counter++;
  $.ajax({
  url: 'addinput.php',
  dataType: "html",
  data: "count="+counter,
  success: function(data) 
  {
     $('#idcover').append(data);

    $('.dua input').keyup(function() 
     {
       var $duaInput = $(this);
       var weight=$duaInput.val(); 
       var score=$duaInput.closest(".group").find('.satu input').val(); 
       $.ajax({
       url: "cekweightscore.php",
       data: "score="+score+"&weight="+weight,
       success: 
       function(data)
       {
         $duaInput.closest(".group").find('.tiga input').val(data);


        }//success
        });//ajax 
    });    

  }//success
  });//ajax  
});

});
function recalc()
{
  var a=$("input[id^=score]");
  var b=$("input[id^=weight]");
    $("[id^=weightscore]").calc("(score * weight)/100",{score: a,weight: b},
        function (s)
        {
          return s.toFixed(2);
        },

        function ($this){
        //function($("[id^=weightscore]")){
            // sum the total of the $("[id^=total_item]") selector
            //alert($this);
            //var sum = $this.sum();
            var sum=$this.sum();
            $("#idtotal").val(sum.toFixed(2));
        }
    );
}

</script>
```

This is the php code:

```
<?
  $count=$_GET['count'];
  echo"
  <br>
  $count
  <div class='group' >
  <div class='satu'>
    <input type='text' name='score[$count][]' id='score[$count][]'>
  </div>
  <div class='dua'>
   <input type='text' name='weight[$count][]' id='weight[$count][]'> %
  </div>
  <div class='tiga'>
  <input type='text' name='weightscore[$count][]' id='weightscore[$count][]' disabled>
  </div>
  </div>";
?>
```

When I click the Add button, i cant get value on new form so that the new form cannot be calculated. What can i do to get total value on dynamic value ?

Comment: `calc` is not a jquery method `$("[id^=weightscore]").calc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember reading this exact same question yesterday and I still have no idea of what you're trying to do.

- Why are you adding inputs through AJAX instead of creating them in Javascript from the beginning? AJAX calls are expensive and are recommended to be used when you need to update/retrieve values from the server.
- Why are you trying to do your calculations on the server side anyway? If you're dealing with dynamic input, you should be doing the calculations client side, then update the server when you're done.
- Why do you use obscure name/id attribute values?

Anyway,
I created [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/6ChSV/), it contains two different solutions, one with a `ul` and a `table`. Hopefully, the example matches what you're trying to do and might give you some insight.

I use a timer to update simulated server data. The timer is set to the variable `update_wait`. The other dynamic calculations are done client side.

I'll post the Javascript code as well, in case you don't like to fiddle

---

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6ChSV/) | Javascript

```
var update_server_timer = null,
    update_wait = 1000; //ms

var decimals = 3;

/**********************
     List solution
**********************/
function CreateListRow(){
    var eLi = document.createElement("li"),
        eScore = document.createElement("div"),
        eWeight = document.createElement("div"),
        eWeightScore = document.createElement("div");

    var next_id = $("#cover li:not(.total)").length + 1

    eScore.className = "score";
    eWeight.className = "weight";
    eWeightScore.className = "weightscore";

    //Score element
    var eScoreInput = document.createElement("input");
    eScoreInput.type = "text";
    eScoreInput.name = "score_"+next_id;
    eScoreInput.id = "score_"+next_id;

    eScore.appendChild(eScoreInput);

    //Weight element
    var eWeightInput = document.createElement("input");
    eWeightInput.type = "text";
    eWeightInput.name = "weight_"+next_id;
    eWeightInput.id = "weight_"+next_id;

    var eWeightPerc = document.createElement("div");
    eWeightPerc.className = "extra";
    eWeightPerc.innerHTML = "%";

    eWeight.appendChild(eWeightInput);
    eWeight.appendChild(eWeightPerc);

    //Weightscore element
    var eWeightScoreInput = document.createElement("input");
    eWeightScoreInput.type = "text";
    eWeightScoreInput.name = "weight_"+next_id;
    eWeightScoreInput.id = "weight_"+next_id;

    eWeightScore.appendChild(eWeightScoreInput);

    $(eScore).keyup(function(){
        CalculateListRow($(this).closest("li"));
    });

    $(eWeight).keyup(function(){
        CalculateListRow($(this).closest("li"));
    });

    //item element
    eLi.appendChild(eScore);
    eLi.appendChild(eWeight);
    eLi.appendChild(eWeightScore);

    return eLi;
}

function CalculateListRowTotal(){
    var fTotal = 0;

    $("#cover li:not(.total) div:nth-child(3) input").each(function(){
        var fVal = parseFloat($(this).val());

        if(isNaN(fVal)) fVal = 0;

        fTotal += fVal;
    });

    fTotal = parseFloat(fTotal.toFixed(decimals));

    $("#cover li.total div input").val(fTotal);

    //Update server variables here
    RestartUpdateServerTimer();
}

function CalculateListRow($Li){
    var fScore = parseFloat($("div.score input", $Li).val()),
        fWeight = parseFloat($("div.weight input", $Li).val())/100,
        fRes = (fScore*fWeight);

    if(isNaN(fRes)) fRes = 0.00;

    $("div.weightscore input", $Li).val(parseFloat(fRes.toFixed(decimals)));

    CalculateListRowTotal();
}

$("#cover li div.weight input, #cover li div.score input").keyup(function(){
    CalculateListRow($(this).closest("li"));
});

function AddListRow(){
    $("#cover li.total").before(CreateListRow());
    RestartUpdateServerTimer();
}

function RemoveListRow(){
    $("#cover li.total").prev().remove();
    CalculateListRowTotal();
}

$(".left_container .menu .add").click(function(){ AddListRow(); });
$(".left_container .menu .rem").click(function(){ RemoveListRow(); });

/**********************
     Table solution
**********************/

function CreateTableRow(){
    var eTr = document.createElement("tr"),
        eTds = [document.createElement("td"),
                document.createElement("td"),
                document.createElement("td")];

    var next_id = $("#cover2 tbody tr").length + 1;


    $(eTds[0]).append(function(){
        var eInput = document.createElement("input");
        eInput.type = "text";
        eInput.name = eInput.id = "score_"+next_id;

        $(eInput).keyup(function(){
            CalculateTableRow($(this).closest("tr"));
        });

        return eInput;
    });

    $(eTds[1]).append(function(){
        var eRelativeFix = document.createElement("div"),
            eInput = document.createElement("input"),
            eExtra = document.createElement("div");

        eRelativeFix.className = "relative_fix";

        eInput.type = "text";
        eInput.name = eInput.id = "weight_"+next_id;

        eExtra.innerHTML = "%";
        eExtra.className = "extra";

        eRelativeFix.appendChild(eInput);
        eRelativeFix.appendChild(eExtra);

        $(eInput).keyup(function(){
            CalculateTableRow($(this).closest("tr"));
        });

        return eRelativeFix;
    });

    $(eTds[2]).append(function(){
        var eInput = document.createElement("input");
        eInput.type = "text";
        eInput.name = eInput.id = "weightscore_"+next_id;

        return eInput;
    });

    for(i = 0; i < eTds.length; i++){
        eTr.appendChild(eTds[i]);
    }

    return eTr;
}

function CalculateTableRowTotals(){
    var $rows = $("#cover2 tbody tr"),
        $totals = $("#cover2 tfoot tr th");

    var fTotal = [];

    //Each row
    $rows.each(function(){
        var $columns = $("td", this);
        //Each column
        $columns.each(function(i, e){
            var fVal = parseFloat($("input", e).val());

            if(isNaN(fVal)) fVal = 0;

            if(isNaN(fTotal[i])) fTotal[i] = 0;

            fTotal[i] += fVal;
        });
    });

    for(i = 0; i < fTotal.length; i++){
        fTotal[i] = parseFloat(fTotal[i].toFixed(decimals));
    }

    fTotal[1] = (fTotal[2]/fTotal[0]*100).toFixed(decimals)+"%";
    fTotal[2] = parseFloat(fTotal[2].toFixed(decimals));

    $totals.each(function(i, e){
        $(this).text(fTotal[i]);
    });

    //Update server variables here
    RestartUpdateServerTimer();
}

function CalculateTableRow($Tr){
    var fScore = parseFloat($("td:nth-child(1) input", $Tr).val()),
        fWeight = parseFloat($("td:nth-child(2) input", $Tr).val())/100,
        fRes = (fScore*fWeight);

    if(isNaN(fRes)) fRes = 0.00;

    $("td:nth-child(3) input", $Tr).val(parseFloat(fRes.toFixed(decimals)));
    CalculateTableRowTotals();
}

function AddTableRow(){
    if($("#cover2 tbody tr").length == 0){
        $("#cover2 tbody").append(CreateTableRow());
    }else{
        $("#cover2 tbody tr:last-child").after(CreateTableRow());
    }

    RestartUpdateServerTimer();
}

function RemoveTableRow(){
    $("#cover2 tbody tr:last-child").remove();
    CalculateTableRowTotals();
}

$(".right_container .menu .add").click(function(){ AddTableRow(); });
$(".right_container .menu .rem").click(function(){ RemoveTableRow(); });

$("#cover2 tbody tr td:nth-child(1) input, #cover2 tbody tr td:nth-child(2) input").keyup(function(){
    CalculateTableRow($(this).closest("tr"));
});

/**********************
     Server data

- Simulates the data on the server,
- whether it be in a SQL server or session data
**********************/

var ServerData = {
    List: {
        Count: 3,
        Total: 5.50
    },
    Table: {
        Count: 3,
        Totals: [65, 8.46, 5.50]
    }
};

function UpdateServerData(){
    //List
    var ListCount = $("#cover li:not(.total)").length,
        ListTotal = $("#cover li.total input").val();

    //Table
    var TableCount = $("#cover2 tbody tr").length,
        TableTotals = [];

    $("#cover2 tfoot th").each(function(i, e){
        TableTotals[i] = parseFloat($(this).text());
    });

    var data = {
        json: JSON.stringify({
            List: {
                Count: ListCount,
                Total: ListTotal
            },
            Table: {
                Count: TableCount,
                Totals: TableTotals
            }
        })
    }

    //Update
    $.ajax({
        url: "/echo/json/",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        type:"POST",
        success: function(response){
            ServerData.List = response.List;
            ServerData.Table = response.Table;

            var displist = "Server data<h1>List</h1><ul><li>Count: "+ServerData.List.Count+"</li><li>Total: "+ServerData.List.Total+"</li></ul>",
                disptable = "<h1>Table</h1><ul><li>Count: "+ServerData.Table.Count+"</li>";

            for(i=0; i<ServerData.Table.Totals.length; i++)
                disptable += "<li>Total "+i+": "+ServerData.Table.Totals[i]+"</li>";
            disptable += "</ul>";

            $("#server_data").html(displist+"<br />"+disptable).effect("highlight");
        }
    });
}

function RestartUpdateServerTimer(){
    if(update_server_timer != null) clearTimeout(update_server_timer);

    update_server_timer = setTimeout(function(){
        UpdateServerData()
    }, update_wait);
}

UpdateServerData();
```

---

### Update

Since you have a hard time grasping the concept, here's a copy paste solution that will work for you without having to use AJAX. I would like to point out that your HTML markup and general coding is a total mess...

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Tj4Sx/) | Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
function CreateInput(){
    var $group = $("<div>"),
        $score = $("<div>"),
        $weight = $("<div>"),
        $weightscore = $("<div>");

    var group_count = $("div.group").length+1;

    $group.addClass("group");
    $score.addClass("satu");
    $weight.addClass("dua");
    $weightscore.addClass("tiga");

    var $input_score = $("<input>"),
        $input_weight = $("<input>"),
        $input_weightscore = $("<input>")

    $input_score
        .attr("name", "score["+group_count+"][]")
        .attr("type", "text")
        .attr("id", "score["+group_count+"][]");

    $input_weight
        .attr("name", "weight["+group_count+"][]")
        .attr("type", "text")
        .attr("id", "weight["+group_count+"][]");

    $input_weightscore
        .attr("name", "weightscore["+group_count+"][]")
        .attr("type", "text")
        .attr("id", "weightscore["+group_count+"][]")
        .attr("disabled", true);

    $input_score.keyup(function(){
        CalculateGroup($(this).parents(".group"));
    });

    $input_weight.keyup(function(){
        CalculateGroup($(this).parents(".group"));
    });

    $score.append($input_score);
    $weight.append($input_weight);
    $weightscore.append($input_weightscore);

    $group.append($score)
          .append($weight)
          .append($weightscore);

    return $group;
}

function CalculateGroup($group){
    var fScore = parseFloat($(".satu input", $group).val()),
        fWeight = parseFloat($(".dua input", $group).val()),
        fWeightScore = parseFloat((fScore*(fWeight/100)).toFixed(2));

    if(isNaN(fWeightScore)) fWeightScore = 0;

    $(".tiga input", $group).val(fWeightScore);
    CalculateTotal();
}

function CalculateTotal(){
    var fWeightScoreTotal = 0;

    $("#idcover div.group div.tiga input").each(function(){
        var fTotal = parseFloat(parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2));

        if(isNaN(fTotal)) fTotal = 0;

        fWeightScoreTotal += fTotal;
    });

    fWeightScoreTotal = parseFloat(fWeightScoreTotal.toFixed(2));

    $("#idtotalcover div.total input").val(fWeightScoreTotal);
}

$(".satu input, .dua input").keyup(function(){
    CalculateGroup($(this).parents(".group"));
});

$("#add_field a").click(function(e){
    $("#idcover").append(CreateInput());

    e.preventDefault();
});

$("#remove_field a").click(function(e){
    $("#idcover div.group:last-child").remove();
    CalculateTotal();

    e.preventDefault();
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: it didnt work.  i had insert `<script type="text/javascript">` between ur javascript. What can i do ?

Comment: @N4tanata ...it's an example script, it doesn't use the same HTML markup that you do. You can't just blindly copy paste. Study the [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/6ChSV/) and try to understand what I'm doing.